# Show $P(\mid X_n \mid \ge \epsilon \cdot n \:\:\mathrm{infinitely}\:\:\mathrm{often}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \Bbb E[\mid X_1 \mid] \lt \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be i.i.d.
I now have to show $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ $$P(\mid X_n \mid \ge \epsilon \cdot n \:\:\mathrm{infinitely}\:\:\mathrm{often}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \Bbb E[\mid X_1  \mid] \lt \infty$$
$$P(\mid X_n \mid \ge \epsilon \cdot n \:\:\mathrm{infinitely}\:\:\mathrm{often}) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \Bbb E[\mid X_1  \mid] = \infty$$

intuitivly the statements are somewhat clear but I don't know how to connect the expectation value and the infinitely often statement. I'm sure one must use Borel-Cantelli somewhere but I'm stuck.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the logical quantifier on $\epsilon$?

Comment: I added it: for all epsilon larger than 0

Comment: This is ambiguous. Do you want us to establish the equivalence for all $\epsilon > 0$ or is the first part of the equivalence a statement that holds for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I want to show that for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ the two equivalences hold

Comment: The first equivalence is false then. The LHS of the first equivalence is supposed to be $\forall \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @mathworker21 No. Actually this RHS holds for some $\epsilon>0$ iff it holds for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Delta: Sorry but I do not see why you do not proceed from the **very precise indication** you have been given. Borel-Cantelli is concerned with limsups of events, the LHS of these equivalences obviously involve limsups, so please make 2 + 2 and see what happens...

Comment: ((Oh, and please replace all these `\mid` by `|`. `\mid` is not made for that.))

Comment: @Did the RHS isn't even in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: @mathworker21 It isn't, and? One is supposed to show that $[P(\epsilon)\iff Q]$ is true for every positive $\epsilon$, where $Q$ does not depend on $\epsilon$, hence you can guess that $[P(\epsilon)\iff P(\eta)]$ for every positive $\epsilon$ and $\eta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\{X_n\}$'s are all independent, the probability of the following event
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega:|X_n(\omega)|\geq n\epsilon \text{ infinitely often}\}
$$
is directly dictated by the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\geq n\epsilon).
$$
Indeed, if this sum is finite, then by the first Borel-Cantelli lemma that the aforementioned event has probability $0$. On the other hand, if this sum is $\infty$, then second Borel-Cantelli lemma tells us that the aforementioned probability is $1$.

Next, using the identicality of distibutions, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\geq n\epsilon)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_1|\geq n\epsilon).
$$
Now we make the following claim.

**Claim**
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_1|\geq n\epsilon) \text{ converges (diverges) }\iff \mathbb{E}[|X|]\text{ converges (diverges) }.
$$
To see why this holds, recall that $\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq x)dx$, and consider a partition $\{n\epsilon:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of real numbers. We can bound the integral via upper and lower Riemann sums corresponding to this partition via
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq n\epsilon)\leq \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X|>x)dx \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq n\epsilon),
$$
hence the sum and integral converge (diverge) together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain where the $\epsilon$ in front of the integral came from? (just from substituting $x\epsilon$ by $x$ ?)  And also how do you see that the probability for the event is dictated by the sum, what's your exact reasoning there? (Sorry for asking again, but apparently I'm not intelligent enough to just add 2 and 2 together as kindly suggested above in the comments).

Comment: There should not be any $\epsilon$, I've edited. So, if you define $A_n = \{|X_n|\geq n\epsilon\}$, then the given event is $A_n \text{ i.o.}$ Then use Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: aah ok i understand now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting, a factor $\epsilon$ was missing, I added it, now it disappeared again and, as a result, the double inequality is again (obviously) wrong (well, except if $\epsilon=1$).

Comment: We don't need a factor of $\epsilon$. Consider $f(x) = \mathbb{P}(|X|>x)$ on $[0,\infty)$. I am taking a partition $\{0,\epsilon,2\epsilon,3\epsilon,\dots.\}$ of $[0,\infty)$ and upper/lower bounding integral using the corresponding Riemann sums.

Comment: More and more interesting... Try $P(X=10\epsilon)=1$ then the sum in the LHS is $10$, the integral is $10\epsilon$ and the sum in the RHS is $11$ hence you are saying that, for every positive $\epsilon$, $$10\leqslant10\epsilon\leqslant11\ ?$$